# How to solve this expo installation problem on macbook?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to install expo on mac but I have the following problem:

```
MBP-de-NOUNJO:desktop pagnol$ sudo npm i -g expo-cli
Password:
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-dKBr48UN
npm ERR! errno -66
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-dKBr48UN'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/pagnol/.npm/_logs/2023-06-24T00_57_55_780Z-debug-0.log
MBP-de-NOUNJO:desktop pagnol$
```

Before this error there was another error, but when I looked on the Internet I was asked to modify the path, which I did and which led me to this error.